# Identify which android app makes which connection

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to find a way within my android application to determine which app is requesting a connection to the internet (or more formally establishes a TCP connection). [Here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=network%20connections&c=apps&hl=en) is an application which already does that.

The above app determines all connections independently without the need of rooting the phone and only with the "Full network access" permission which is magnificent.

I am currently developing with the help of this [source](https://github.com/felixb/adBlock/blob/master/src/de/ub0r/android/adBlock/Proxy.java), a proxy server on android and I can easily read the connections the phone establishes over the Internet.

How do I determine which application is actually requesting the specific TCP (http/https) connection?

Answer (score 0):

I came in contact with Peter, a developer of the mentioned application and he was very kind to provide an answer regarding in discovering connections.

Here is his answer:

You can find the network information in the standard kernel proc files, like in any other Linux distribution:

/proc/[pid]/net/tcp

/proc/[pid]/net/tcp6

/proc/[pid]/net/udp

/proc/[pid]/net/udp6

/proc/[pid]/net/raw

/proc/[pid]/net/raw6

The [pid] is the process id of your app, but each file holds information about all network connections for the corresponding protocol.